# How to install the WordPress component a jQuery Plug-in in GitHub

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins, github

I am new to WordPress, but need to use it so I can add a jQuery Plug-In to a github repository. The WordPress instructions at https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com are confusing to a beginner.

In particular, the instructions for Redirecting the WordPress install to use the "web-base-template" allude me (I am a Windows user). I am also confused on how to "Activate the plugins-jquery-com theme".

Please note that I do understand the jQuery Plug-In site is still under construction.

Any help on either of these issues is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Replacing `wp-content`

> In particular, the instructions for Redirecting the WordPress install to use the "web-base-template" allude me (I am a Windows user).

They're telling you to delete the `wp-content` folder that comes with WordPress and replace it with their own, by making `wp-content` a symbolic link to `web-base-template/wordpress/wp-content`.  If you're on Windows then you don't have symbolic links.  I wonder if this will work at all on Windows, because it looks like there are symbolic links in the `jquery/web-base-template` repo.  I was going to suggest that you try setting up your directory stucture something like this...

```
docroot
  wordpress
  base
  flat
  themes
```

...then copy `web-base-template/wordpress/wp-content` to `wordpress/wp-content`.  But, if the `jquery/web-base-template` software is built to be dependent on things like symbolic links, I don't know if you'll be able to get it to work in Windows.  You could try copying things around to eliminate symbolic links, e.g. copy `web-base-template/themes` to `wordpress/wp-content/themes`, but I'm not sure if you'd be able to maintain the necessary relationships between directories for relative paths to continue to work, or if other things would prevent it from working.  I imagine that would also make it harder to be able to update from the `jquery/web-base-template` repo in the future.

## Activating theme

> I am also confused on how to "Activate the plugins-jquery-com theme".

Once you followed their preceeding instructions, in `WordPress Admin > Appearance > Themes` you'd have the option to activate the `plugins-jquery-com` theme, to apply the theme to your site.

## Recommendations

I recommend that you try doing a standard [WordPress install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) first, and also try installing and activating a [theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) , just to become more familiar with the WordPress part of it before attempting to follow the plugins.jquery.com instructions.  I think that would be a good idea anyway, but even more so because the plugins.jquery.com stuff does not work within the standard WordPress directory structure.  It's using its own custom directory structure and replacing WordPress's `wp-content` directory with a link into that custom structure.

I know it's not your question, but perhaps you should consider running a Linux installation (e.g. Ubuntu) in a virtual machine and do the WordPress installation there.  I realize that is probably also more extra work, on top of dealing with WordPress, to accomplish the jQuery work you're really trying to do.

Comment: Thanks JMM. After following your instructions, I do believe I'm on the way to completing the installation. Here's a link to the wp site: http://wp.bunkerhill.com/wordpress/

Comment: I see that you have a theme now, looks like you're making progress.  What exactly are you trying to do, are you just trying to get a jQuery plugin listed on the new site once it's up and running?  Is that `jquery/plugins.jquery.com` repo and all the WordPress stuff for working on the plugins site itself, as opposed to just listing a plugin?  I just took a look at it again and it sounds like they're saying if you just want to list a plugin you just need to put it in a GitHub repo with a `package.json` file of their specification, and a `post-receive` hook.

Comment: Your comment about using Linux turns out to be key. The plug-in instructions require Node.js to be installed and my Hosting provider does not allow on Windows. What I really wanted to do was provide a the standardized jQuery plug-in compliant github experience, but what I will settle for is just adding a blog to my current page (jquery.bunkerhill.com) and a github repository as well. Is it possible/easy to add just the blog portion of wp to an existing page?

Comment: You want something like jquery.bunkerhill.com/blog/? Should be able to do that. Matching the appearnce of the WordPress part to the rest of the site would take more work, setting up a custom theme. If you're willing to use a pre-existing WordPress theme it will be simpler.  Take a look at [Famous 5-Minute Install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install), [In a Subdirectory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#In_a_Subdirectory). Apache URL rewriting is really helpful with apps like WordPress, so I don't know how you'll fare without that.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install jQuery plug-in in Githup are available [here](https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com/blob/master/README.md)
hope this can help you :)

in this steps if you find any error please let me know.